# ManyRelatedManager object is not iterable

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-templates

Tengo el modelo `FrequentAskedQuestion` que tiene un campo relacionado `models.ManyToManyField(Tag)` y está definido así:

```py
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Nombre", max_length=50)


class FrequentAskedQuestion(models.Model):
    ...
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    ...
```

En el sistema de administración, me aparecen las etiquetas correctamente como una lista multiselección. El problema aparece a la hora de obtener las etiquetas desde la vista.

Actualmente, esto tiene mi vista que controla el detalle de un objeto:

```py
def faq_view(request, id):
    faq = FrequentAskedQuestion.objects.get(id=id)
    print(faq)
    context = { 'faq': faq }
    return render(request, 'detail.html', context)
```

Y luego el archivo `detail.html`:

```html
<div class="tag-list">
    {% for tag in faq.tags %}
        <span class="badge bg-secondary">{{ tag.name }}</span>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        {{ faq.content | safe }}%
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Sin agregar el tema de las etiquetas, esto funciona correctamente. El problema es que así como está arriba me da el error:

> 'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable

¿Ideas cómo puedo iterar `faq.tags`?

Comment: `{% for tag in faq.tags.all %}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es un error bastante común cuando se empieza con Django.

Si tienes un objeto en una plantilla y quieres obtener datos relacionados, no es suficiente `objeto.objetos_relacionados` sino que tienes que añadir `.all` para que resulte un QuerySet.

```
{% block X %}
<div class="tag-list">
    {% for tag in faq.tags.all %}                                 # añade .all
        <span class="badge bg-secondary">{{ tag.name }}</span>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        {{ faq.content | safe }}%
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Espero que con esto se solucione tu problema.

Comment: lo solucionó, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

te comento que para iterar un campo ManyToMany en un template se hace de esta manera:

```
<div class="tag-list">
    {% for tag in faq.tags.all %}
        <span class="badge bg-secondary">{{ tag.name }}</span>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        {{ faq.content | safe }}%
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Podrías rodear el for con un {% if faq.tags.all %}

Si lo quieres hacer a nivel python, se hace de la siguiente manera:

```
for tag in faq.tags.all():
    print(tag)
```

Comment: fueron practicamente al mismo tiempo, pero sólo puedo seleccionar uno. Gracias de todas maneras.